# Unable to modify MaxClients on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have run Apache buddy and it suggests I lower my MaxClients setting in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. It also reports that Apache is using prefork model. So I lower the MaxClients value in apache2.conf here:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
   StartServers          2
   MinSpareServers       2
   MaxSpareServers       5
   MaxClients           12
   MaxRequestsPerChild   3000
</IfModule>
```

I restart apache, run Apache Buddy again, it reports the value as unchanged. What am I missing? This is on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is this [Apache Buddy](https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl)?  If so, it ignores anything inside `<IfModule>` blocks and defaults to 256 if it can't find `MaxClients`.  There appears to be multiple tools called "Apache Buddy" so let me know if I've found the wrong one.